# Does using exists() and count() together make sense?

Tags: django, django-orm

Does it make sense to do this?

```
if Model.objects.filter(...).exists():
   c = Model.objects.filter(...).count()
```

Is it less database expensive than this?

```
c = Model.objects.filter(...).count()
```

I'm thinking in terms of time spent on the DB. Your opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that objects do exist, doing two queries is less efficient than doing one.

In the case that no objects exist, I can't think why `exists()` would be noticeably faster than `count()`.

So I would stick with:

```
c = Model.objects.filter(...).count()
```

One disadvantage of doing `exists()` first is that you have not set `c` when `exists()` returns `False`. This could lead to `NameError` if you're not careful.